# Linear Matrix Sorting

Tags: sorting

I have a linear vector, within which contains the unit coordinates of any given block. The coordinate system is shown below. What would be the best method for sorting the list if I wanted the final list starting from the bottom left and ending at the top right? Changing the data structure is not an option.

Any means of explanation will do; pseudo, code, rough idea, etc.

[image: Diagram of data to be sorted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are as follows.

1. Column major

   Order by y descending, then by x increasing, using a dictionary ordering.
2. Row major

   Order by x increasing, then by y descending, using a dictionary ordering.

To illustrate, here is a C-style example comparison operation for option 1.

```
int compare(point a, point b)
{
    if (a.y > b.y)
        return -1;
    else if (a.y < b.y)
        return 1;
    else if (a.x < b.x)
        return -1;
    else if (a.x > b.x)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

It appears based on the "#n" labels on the blocks that you want option 1, column major.

Comment: Perfect, just one small change I made was swap the return values -1 to 1, and 1 to -1 to implement the column ranking based sort. Thanks for your help Mr. Shields!